# How to override property setter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Need to override property setter of the parent class. In order to temporary block assignment. For example - selectedRange property of the UITextView. How can I do this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-(void)setFoo:(Foo *)newFoo {
  // Do something.
  [super setFoo: newFoo];
}
```

If you want to block the setter sometimes,

```
-(void)setFoo:(Foo *)newFoo {
  if (someCondition) {
    [super setFoo: newFoo];
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: doing this on Apple-provided APIs can, in some cases, cause your application to be denied from the store.